# What are the general word order trends of VO languages

Tags: syntax, word-order, svo, vso

I’ve heard that some scholars collapse SVO, VSO, and VOS into one general category of VO.

From what I understand, these VO languages allegedly exhibit strong and weak common word order trends.

If this category is valid, what are these trends, and how consistent are these trends?

Comment: What research have you done on this? Can you show us?

Comment: Lehmann (March 1973) proposed that SVO, VSO, and VOS are all part of a broader VO category. I forget where I read this, but this may be an over generalization, despite their similarities. I want to know what the similarities are.

Comment: I don't know about "trends".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, see https://wals.info/chapter/83 "Order of object and verb", section 3 on "Theoretical issues". (Your question would seem to require a survey article or a book as an answer).